# Adding a date from one of my tables to a date_add

Tags: mysql

Is there anyway of adding a date from my tables to an date_add? For example, in the code, i want to change 2009-05-25 to a date that exists from a table. Thanks in advance.

```
select date_format( date_add("2009-05-25",interval 2500 day),"%d - %m - %Y" )
as fire_date;
```

Comment: I think you may need to show us an example of what you want to achieve

Answer (score 0):

Just use the column name instead of  "2009-05-25"

```
select date_format( date_add(my_column_name,interval 2500 day),"%d - %m - %Y" ) as fire_date;
```